# Can't generate reports using PRPT (Kettle Job)

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to generate reports using prpt from java code. But it's failing while writing data to the pdf file, looks like jar issue.

Note: Invoking prpt file from the Kettle job.

I've tried excluded all `xml-apis` maven dependencies from the project.

```java
KettleEnvironment.init();
JobMeta jobmeta = new JobMeta(fileName, repository);
Job job = new Job(repository, jobmeta);
job.initializeVariablesFrom(null);
job.getJobMeta().setInternalKettleVariables(job);
for(Entry<String, String> param: params.entrySet()) {
    jobmeta.setParameterValue(param.getKey(), param.getValue());
}
job.copyParametersFrom(jobmeta);
job.activateParameters();

job.execute(0, null);
job.waitUntilFinished();
job.setFinished(true);
```

Error message:

```
Caused by: org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException: Caught Kettle Exception: Check your configuration
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.kettle.KettleDataFactory.queryData(KettleDataFactory.java:100)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryStaticInternal(CompoundDataFactory.java:172)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryStatic(CompoundDataFactory.java:154)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.cache.CachingDataFactory.queryInternal(CachingDataFactory.java:408)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.cache.CachingDataFactory.queryStatic(CachingDataFactory.java:151)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryStaticInternal(CompoundDataFactory.java:168)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryStatic(CompoundDataFactory.java:154)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryData(CompoundDataFactory.java:67)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.DefaultFlowController.performQueryData(DefaultFlowController.java:256)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.DefaultFlowController.performQuery(DefaultFlowController.java:192)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.process.ProcessState.initializeForMasterReport(ProcessState.java:318)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.prepareReportProcessing(AbstractReportProcessor.java:442)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.processReport(AbstractReportProcessor.java:1433)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.pdf.PdfExportTask.run(PdfExportTask.java:134)
       at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.PentahoReportingOutput.processReport(PentahoReportingOutput.java:278)
       ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
       at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.util.XMLParserFactoryProducer.createSecureDocBuilderFactory(XMLParserFactoryProducer.java:36)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.xmlns.parser.DomTreeResourceFactory.create(DomTreeResourceFactory.java:75)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.DefaultResourceManagerBackend.create(DefaultResourceManagerBackend.java:225)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.docbundle.BundleResourceManagerBackend.create(BundleResourceManagerBackend.java:142)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:382)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:334)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.kettle.KettleTransFromFileProducer.loadTransformation(KettleTransFromFileProducer.java:124)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.kettle.AbstractKettleTransformationProducer.performQuery(AbstractKettleTransformationProducer.java:232)
       at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.kettle.KettleDataFactory.queryData(KettleDataFactory.java:96)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution for this from some blog. The solution is adding the below dependency in the pom file.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>xerces</groupId>
<artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
<version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>`
```

Adding this dependency resolved my issue java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V